# How to expand TopAppBar programmatically?

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, material-components-android

`MediumTopAppBar` and `LargeTopAppBar` have expanded and closed state.

`EnterAlwaysScrollBehavior` will immediately collapse when the content is pulled up, and will immediately appear when the content is pulled down. (from the doc)

If scrolled down and the page body content changes it'll still be in the closed state as expected. But I want to trigger an expanded state back when say content changed or a button is pressed without the user scrolling up.

What I need:

A method or workaround to change the `TopAppBar` state to expand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have the LargeTopAppBar scroll behaviour as

```
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
```

and the LargeTopAppBar as

```
Scaffold(
                topBar = {
                    LargeTopAppBar(
                        title = { Text(text = "title") },
                        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
                    )
                },
                floatingActionButton = {
                    FloatingActionButton(
                        onClick = {
                            if (scrollBehavior.state.heightOffset < 0.0) {
                                //expand the LargeTopAppBar
                                scrollBehavior.state.heightOffset = 0f
                            } else {
                                //collapse the LargeTopAppBar
                                scrollBehavior.state.heightOffset = -242f
                            }

                        }
                    ) {
                    }
                },
            ) {}
```

I tried setting the offset to -1000f, it still performs the same function

Comment: So, what does a negative offset mean actually?

Comment: From the log files i receive when monitoring the offset, a negative offset means the topAppBar is collapsed (or closed). The offset is only 0.0 when it is fully expanded